# Changing form of numbers in R (i.e. 3.900163e-02 -> 0.03900163)

Tags: r, numbers, format

I have a column that has decimal numbers (more than 50,000 rows).
but the numbers are expressed as a form like this -> 3.900163e-02
How can I change this number to 0.03900163 in R?

Comment: You cannot. They are the same number. Perhaps you need either `?format` or `?options`.

Comment: You can use `sprintf` or `formatC`. try `formatC(3.900163e-02, digits = 7)`

Answer (score 3):

As it was mentioned they are the same numbers, but if you want to print them in different format use `format` function:

```
x <- 0.000000000001
x
## [1] 1e-12
format(x, scientific=FALSE)
## [1] "0.000000000001"
```